# Use RESTful routes and POST parameters

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rest, ruby-on-rails-4

I have a website for a college that tracks student information and serves it up to faculty advisors, most of which is confidential.  Many features in this site involve passing a student's ID number to the controller.  Because student ID numbers are confidential I am curious if I can avoid having the student's ID appear in the URL string as a parameter.  Here is what I have investigated so far:

Rather than passing a student's ID via GET I could POST the ID number. This would work fine, but then I am confused on how I could make use of RESTful route helper methods, when the router expects a GET request and I am sending a POST request.  Is it possible to customize around this?

A second idea (which I fear might be a bit unelegant) is to store a hash in session data where some arbitrary number served to the user is the key to that students ID number. That arbitrary number appears in the URL string rather than the id number.

The other alternative I can think of is to not use restful resources at all. This is completely doable, but I want to see if there are any other options.

Or is there anything I'm not thinking of (very possible).

Thanks,

Comment: In case you can change the existing application ... You are perfectly ok with doing it the REST way. You do not have to mess with session and hash inside of it. Exposing this type of data - **IN THIS CASE** - id number as a url string parameter is bad practice. Instead go for something called surrogate key - artificial guid, which is uniform, generated, independent from the student and does not expose students' personal data. For other benefits look ath the linked wikipedia article.


https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Surrogate_key

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you may be confusing two different ideas here. Your students may have a unique id number to identify them in the educational system or the school records much like a [National identification number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/National_identification_number). But you do not / should not use that number to identify the records in your rails app.

Instead you would have a normal auto incrementing column in the database to identify students in your application. There is no real reason that the number should be confidential.

Answer (score 0):

The idea behind REST is to use each one of the methods supported GET, POST, PUT, and DELETE in the right scenario.

If the only concern that you have is that the student Id showing in the URL, I suggest that you use the record id (the one that is autoincremented automatically by the database) not the real Id of the student in the requests and add the real ID as an extra field in the table.

Cheers